# Не могу подсоединиться к Minio через Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minio

У меня есть следующий Docker-Compose файл:

```
services:
  filehostingapp.api:
    image: filehostingapp.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FileHostingApp.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Host=postgres;Port=5432;Database=HostingBase;Username=postgres;Password=admin
      - AWS__ServiceURL=http://s3:9000
      - AWS__AccessTokenId=minioadmin
      - AWS__SecretKey=minioadmin
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - s3
      - pgadmin
  s3:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - minio_storage:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minioadmin
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minioadmin
    command: server --address ":9000" --console-address ":9001" /data
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "HostingBase"
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "admin"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "testmail@mail.ru"
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "admin"
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: "False"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1G
    
volumes:
  minio_storage: {}
  pgadmin-data: {}
```

Как видно, в filehostingapp.api я пытаюсь подсоединиться к minio, используя имя контейнера. На что получаю

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known (files.s3:9000)
```

Я пробовал:
Создавать network
Убирать http

По итогу - ничего. Везде в интернете пишут, что именно так нужно получать хост контейнера. Они вроде как по умолчанию в одной сети.

Comment: а контейнер то стартанул? что в `docker ps` ?
и есть ли доступ к 127.0.0.1:9001